# Node.js and MSSQL stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

What would be the suggested way (if even possible) to call MSSQL SP from Node.js. The documentation https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql is great but there is no mention of SP (stored procedure) anywhere.

Comment: yes it does mention stored procedures. ctrl+F in the webpage you've linked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [linked document](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql) does actually mention stored procedures:

```
var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, 10);
    request.output('output_parameter', sql.VarChar(50));
    request.execute('procedure_name', function(err, recordsets, returnValue) {
        // ... error checks

        console.dir(recordsets);
    });
```

Not sure it's wise to answer this question, but it might be valueable for future readers/googlers.

Comment: My bad, appreciate your time

Comment: hi @david Mulder.. i am trying to execute a stored procedure  which doesn't  accept any parameters but returns a table.. what changes should be made in order to get the response ?

Comment: Then how do you check the return value? I tried: 
var parm = request.output('output_parameter').value and var parm = request.output('output_parameter').value but got [object] or undefined.

Comment: Using return values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669183/how-to-access-the-output-parameter-in-node-mssql

Answer (score 4):

It's getting better with ES6/7 additions to JS. This is how you can do it with [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```js
async function getDataFromProcedure(dbConfig, procedureName) {
  try {
    await sql.connect(dbConfig);
    const request = new sql.Request();
    recordsets = await request.execute(procedureName);
    return recordsets[0];
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error here
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate async/await syntax. I like the .then() format.

```
return await this.sqlConnectionPool.connect().then(async (pool) => {
  return await pool
    .request()
    .input("UserID", sql.Int, id)
    .execute("spADF_User_Get")
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.recordset && result.recordset.length === 1) {
        return result.recordset[0];
      } else {
        //Something bad happened
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: why mix the two? I only do it if I have to, like promisifying an event-based library... This seems like it would work but adds confusion about where to set the breakpoints vs. @vitkon's answer where it goes straight through (as long as it's a single request)