# How to access the output parameter in node mssql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mssql

```
`  request.input('xyz',sql.Int,1);
    request.input('abc',sql.Numeric,2);
    request.output('pqr',sql.Int);
    request.output('def',sql.Char);
      request.execute('[StoredProcedure]',function(err,recordsets,returnvalue){
      next.ifError(err);
      console.log(returnvalue);
    })`
```

Now the problem is how will i access the output parameters.

Regards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`request.parameters.pqr.value` and `request.parameters.def.value`

Got the answer , so sharing it :)

Comment: You saved me a day. Thanks so much!

Comment: I dont understand your answer, can yoy please give me the code? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually the method described above did not work for me using `"mssql": "^4.3.0"`.

I had to use the result object returned by the promise and extract the parameters from the `output` object. Something like:

res.output.

Here is the sample code which worked for me:

```
poolPromise
        .then(conn => conn.request())
        .then(request => {
            const forecastName = forecastDefinition.name;
            // Input parameters
            request.input('forecastName', sql.VarChar(50), forecastName);
            ...
            // Output parameters
            request.output('actualYear', sql.Int);
            request.output('actualMonth', sql.Int);
            ...
            return request.execute('[dbo].[' + generateForecastProcedure + ']')
        })
        .then((res, err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`${generateForecastProcedure} error: `, err);
            } else {
                console.log(`${generateForecastProcedure} success: `, res);
                // Callback to deal with further processing.
                const output = (res.output || {});
                const actualYear = output.actualYear;
                const actualMonth = output.actualMonth;
                callback(forecastDefinition, actualYear, actualMonth);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`${generateForecastProcedure} exception: `, err);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

After analysing 1 hour, I found this. Hope it will be useful to someone

Instead of this **request.parameters.SQLReturn** you can use  **recordsets.output.SQLReturn**

```
request.output("SQLReturn");

            request.execute('sample', function (err, recordsets, returnValue, results) {    


                    res.json({ code: 1, message: recordsets.output.SQLReturn });
                }
```